# Unable to build as dependencies are missing in recipe-sysroot - yocto

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I'm trying to build mxnet 1.6.0 with Yocto (Rocko) for my 64-bit Armv8-A.
First of all, I have downloaded mxnet from https://downloads.apache.org/incubator/mxnet/1.6.0/ .
I have kept the downloaded tar in files folder in one of the layers. and i have included that tar file in my **mxnet.bb** file as shown below.

**mxnet.bb**

```
SUMMARY = "MXNET Package"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

PN = 'mxnet'
PV = '1.6.0'

DEPENDS = "openblas opencv gtest gperftools"

SRC_URI := " \
    file://apache-mxnet-src-1.6.0-incubating.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "76802d6b14cd45c27f063b2bba3c9a14"

S := "${WORKDIR}/apache-${PN}-src-${PV}-incubating"

inherit cmake pkgconfig

OECMAKE_GENERATOR = "Unix Makefiles"

EXTRA_OECMAKE += " -DUSE_SSE=OFF \
-DUSE_CUDA=OFF \
-DUSE_OPENCV=ON \
-DUSE_OPENMP=ON \
-DUSE_MKL_IF_AVAILABLE=OFF \
-DUSE_SIGNAL_HANDLER=ON \
-DUSE_LAPACK=OFF"
```

- Then I built it using **bitbake mnxet** command.
  I got the below error.

**ERROR:**

```
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
| -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
| -- Detecting CXX compile features
| -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
| -- CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE
| -- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64
| -- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64
| -- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux
| -- CMake version '3.14.1' using generator 'Unix Makefiles'
| -- Performing Test SUPPORT_CXX11
| -- Performing Test SUPPORT_CXX11 - Success
| -- Performing Test SUPPORT_CXX0X
| -- Performing Test SUPPORT_CXX0X - Success
| -- Determining F16C support
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_MF16C
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_MF16C - Failed
| -- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
| -- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
| CMake Error at cmake/Modules/FindOpenBLAS.cmake:82 (MESSAGE):
|   Could not find OpenBLAS
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   cmake/ChooseBlas.cmake:42 (find_package)
|   CMakeLists.txt:310 (include)
| 
| 
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

- I checked in `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/openblas/0.3.5-r0/image/opt/openblas/lib` and found .so and .a files.
- I noticed that in
  `build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mxnet/1.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/lib64`,
  there is no `libopenblas.so` or openblas folder.
- I also checked `build/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/openblas`
  and found that there's only `sysroot-providers` in it and no `opt/openblas/lib` or any opt or lib folder (I can't find files present in my image folder of openblas as mentioned above).

**So, the question is, How do i add openblas to my recipe-sysroot in mxnet? so that it should not throw couldn't find openblas error?**

p.s. I could build openblas only if my .so files were present in /opt/openblas/lib path. Else, if i try to put .so files in just /lib folder, it would throw me a `Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package` error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add

```
FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/libmxnet.so"
```

to the recipe.

Comment: my build didn't even go till ```do_package```. Error's at ```do_compile``` stage and it seems it is unable to find openblas. When i did cmake from source i was able to solve this by coping ```/opt/openblas/lib/*``` to ```/usr/lib64``` and  ```/opt/openblas/include/*``` to ```/usr/include```